# Spring boot get the specified config properties in service class

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my existing project, I have one config class which reads some properties from a YAML file related to a specific API. According to these properties service class hit the API and process the response. The config class is something like that:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "apiA")
public class APIConfigA {
private String apiName;
private String apiKey;
private String apiUrl;
//other properties and getter setters
```

This is used in service is something like that:

```
 @Service
 public class APIResponseParser
 @Autowired
 public JsonParserService(APIConfig apiConfig) {
    this.apiConfig = apiConfig;
    // other properties
}
```

Now I need to onboard a new API for ex: apiB which have some other properties in a separate YAML file. What can I do with minimal changes in existing `APIResponseParser` class so that `this.apiConfig` can read the apiB properties so my `APIResponseParser` can be generic.

My new config file for apiB which is reading properties from different YMAL

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "apiB")
public class APIConfigB {
private String apiName;
private String apiKey;
private String apiUrl;
//other properties and getter setters
```

what I tried so far created one new `interface` with name `Config` and both config classes are implementing the `Config` `interface`

```
public class APIConfigA implements Config{
 // other properties
 private Config APIConfigA;
 // getter and setter
  @Qualifier("1.2")
  public void setConfig(Config APIConfigA) {
      this.APIConfigA = APIConfigA;
  }
}

public class APIConfigB implements Config{
 // other properties
 private Config APIConfigB;
 // getter and setter
  @Qualifier("1.5")
  public void setNewConfig(Config APIConfigB) {
      this.APIConfigB = APIConfigB;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the config 'A' and 'B' has same no of properties and same type?

Comment: For now ,Yes both have the same no of properties and type but in future requirements they might be different.

Comment: JsonParserService depends upon APIConfig. So need to maintain two beans of JsonParserService . If you wish to have some logic inside your JsonParserService class to get the respective APIConfig then I can suggest something.

Comment: In jsonParsorService in many places we are using existing APIConfigA which reads the properties from Yaml file. What I want if i can inject APIConfigB object somehow. Its okay to make changes in jsonparserservice